# PHP ↔ JavaScript communication : constants VS strings

Tags: php, javascript

I am developping a web-application which makes a heavy use of AJAX. The server often answer by an array in order to *concatenate* different parts of the response.

I wonder what is the best solution to handle the keys in those arrays among the following two (the JSON encoding and decoding aren't shown):

#### Strings

This solution is easy to read, especially in JavaScript, but is really brittle and hard to maintain.

*PHP* :

```
<?php
return array(
    'key_name_1' => 'foo',
    'key_name_2' => 'bar'
);
?>
```

*JavaScript* :

```
var result = ajax(...);
alert(result.key_name_1);
```

#### Constants

This is a solid solution, which allow for short and numeric keys, but it's heavy and hard to read (use Reflection to automatize the generation of JavaScript constants is not an acceptable solution in my case, and doesn't solve all the drawbacks anyway).

*PHP* :

```
<?php
class Answer
{
    const CONSTANT_1 = 1;
    const CONSTANT_2 = 2;
}

return array(
    Answer::CONSTANT_1 => 'foo',
    Answer::CONSTANT_2 => 'bar'
);
?>
```

*JavaScript* :

```
Answer.CONSTANT_1 = <?php echo Answer::CONSTANT_1; ?>
Answer.CONSTANT_2 = <?php echo Answer::CONSTANT_2; ?>

var result = ajax(...);
alert(result[Answer.CONSTANT_1]);
```

---

According to you, what is the best choice?

Comment: Wouldn't you want the keys to be named after the value you they store?

Comment: I am a fan of readable code.  Help me understand why the string solution is brittle and hard to maintain.  Also help me understand why, if you use a constant for a numeric index, you couldn't use a constant string for an index?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Was an exemple. My constants have naturally more readable (and acceptable) names.

Comment: @Blackhole why don't the keys themselves have naturally more readable (and acceptable) names?

Comment: @J.D.Pace For numeric index, I was talking about the value of the constant. We can't reasonably use numeric keys without using constants, right ? I think the string solution is brittle, since any change in key name must also be perform in the code which use them. But that also the case with the other solution, I guess…

Comment: @J.D.Pace More readable names in constants value are useless, because those names are carried by the constants name. Obfuscate a little the communication between server and client is a good point in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the string solution is brittle, since any change in key name
>   must also be perform in the code which use them.

This conclusion is incorrect and will lead to unmaintainable code.

Consider the following PHP data structures:

```
array(
 MyClass::FIELD1 => "my field1 value",
 MyClass::FIELD2 => "my field2",
 MyClass::FIELD3 => "field 3 is awesome",
);

class MyClass {
  const FIELD1 = "field1";
  const FIELD2 = "field2";
  const FIELD3 = "field3";
}
```

Assume that we want to use a new field in place of `field1` (as in the suggested use case) -  we'll call it `newfield`:

```
class MyClass {
  const FIELD1 = "newfield";
  ....
}
```

Now the code is in an inconsistent state. *The name of the variable no longer has any correlation to it's value.* The `FIELD1` constant is essentially *lying* about the field it represents.

Imagine a new programmer examining this code a year later. She knows `newfield` exists and wants to access it. But instead of simply typing in `result.newfield` she has to enter `result[Answer.FIELD1]`.  And every time she wants to access `newfield` she has the mental overhead of remembering and applying this mapping. But this is a large application with hundreds of fields and most are misdirected in this way. This is brittle and unmaintainable code.

Constants should only be used for values that are *constant* in nature. The canonical example being storing mathematical constants like pi:

```
class MyMathClass {
  const PI = 3.141592;
}
```

Constants are one of the worst programming tools available for maintaining a volatile data structure (field names changing on a regular basis).

Comment: Wow, that's a really clear and precise explanation ! Thank you very much !

Comment: But what if the constants value are numerics, just in order to differenciate the keys and no to have any meaning ? There is no more this problem of correlation, right ?

Comment: Maybe. Even in that case it's probably best just to use numbers for lookup. For instance if I want the first field of a collection I'd rather use `results[0]` than `results[Answer.FIELD1]`. A possible exception might be if the number has special meaning. Like the result with an id of `50` should display differently in the interface. In which case you could represent it with `Answer.HIGHLIGHT_FIELD_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you echo it out JavaScript it will not really be a constant anyway. I would personally use strings if it's going to make your code more readable down the line. Why would this make it brittle and hard to maintain? You could always define a constant string if you need it to be both constant and readable. It's hard to tell without more information if you will be better-served with numbers or words as your keys.